# How can I open a PWA programmatically?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, google-chrome-app

Is it possible to open a progressive web app (desktop PWA) immediately when the user clicks the URL of your web app in another website or another PWA?

Comment: What you are looking for is deep-linking :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45979191/deep-linking-from-web-to-pwa-standalone-version

Comment: This used to work but I believe no SW is instantiated unless a browser instance is running https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients/openWindow