# How to achieve Deep Linking for PWAs on iOS?

Tags: ios, push-notification, progressive-web-apps, deep-linking

I've read a few threads on this but most threads are dated and got some mixed feedback. Here's an old thread:
[Deep linking from Web to PWA (Standalone Version)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45979191/deep-linking-from-web-to-pwa-standalone-version)

Here's an [article]([https://www.appdome.com/how-to/securing-workplace-apps/secure-progressive-web-apps/build-a-secure-ios-android-pwa-with-deep-links/#:~:text=To](https://www.appdome.com/how-to/securing-workplace-apps/secure-progressive-web-apps/build-a-secure-ios-android-pwa-with-deep-links/#:%7E:text=To) use deep links%2C customers,page represented by the URL) from a PWA service that seems to achieve it using a prefix URL method:
To use deep links, customers can create a link or URL with the prefix ***appdome pwa://***and include that link in a website or send it by email, SMS. When the mobile user clicks on the link, it will open the iOS or Android PWA (if installed) and display the specific page represented by the URL.

Intercom wrote a [blog post](https://intercom.help/progressier/en/articles/6902113-complete-guide-to-pwa-deep-links) in early 2023 that said it is only possible through PWA push notifications with iOS 16.4+

Appreciate the help!

I tried finding an anwer but most of the threads are dated.